# Keycloak- SpringBoot Adapter - Infinite loop when sending /sso/login

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, keycloak

I have a JavaScript (JQuery) application that sends an Api request to a Spring Boot application that is using Keycloak SpringBoot Adapter.

After the user login lets say that

1 - All Realm sessions are logout using the Keycloak admin console

2 - The Spring Boot application is restarted

3 - The Browser session cookies remain unchanged (last login)

When I try to login into the application again I get the following exception

```
162708 2021-09-14 14:47:10,070 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler ?:? - adminRequest https://[my-server]/sso/login?state=60f81726-6bec-470a-90b2-2f62dfb2d2f1&session_state=f4593998-e3cb-444a-94b6-1e53ab77267d&code=85df1b52-246e-4839-9b7a-c481e1e577c2.f4593998-e3cb-444a-94b6-1e53ab77267d.442a440e-6df0-40c7-b8cb-3a52123430a0
162708 2021-09-14 14:47:10,070 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler ?:? - checkCorsPreflight https://[my-server]/sso/login?state=60f81726-6bec-470a-90b2-2f62dfb2d2f1&session_state=f4593998-e3cb-444a-94b6-1e53ab77267d&code=85df1b52-246e-4839-9b7a-c481e1e577c2.f4593998-e3cb-444a-94b6-1e53ab77267d.442a440e-6df0-40c7-b8cb-3a52123430a0
162708 2021-09-14 14:47:10,070 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter ?:? - Attempting Keycloak authentication
162708 2021-09-14 14:47:10,070 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] TRACE org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator ?:? - --> authenticate()
162709 2021-09-14 14:47:10,071 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] TRACE org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator ?:? - try bearer
162709 2021-09-14 14:47:10,071 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] TRACE org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator ?:? - try query parameter auth
162709 2021-09-14 14:47:10,071 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] TRACE org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator ?:? - try oauth
162709 2021-09-14 14:47:10,071 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.SpringSecurityTokenStore ?:? - Checking if org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticator@bd9ec13 is cached
162709 2021-09-14 14:47:10,071 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator ?:? - there was a code, resolving
162709 2021-09-14 14:47:10,071 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator ?:? - checking state cookie for after code
162709 2021-09-14 14:47:10,071 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator ?:? - ** reseting application state cookie
162727 2021-09-14 14:47:10,089 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] ERROR org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator ?:? - failed to turn code into token
162727 2021-09-14 14:47:10,089 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] ERROR org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator ?:? - status from server: 400
162728 2021-09-14 14:47:10,090 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] ERROR org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator ?:? -    {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code not valid"}
162728 2021-09-14 14:47:10,090 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter ?:? - Auth outcome: FAILED
162740 2021-09-14 14:47:10,102 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter ?:? - Failed to process authentication request
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakAuthenticationException: Invalid authorization header, see WWW-Authenticate header for details
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:162)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
```

This is what I get in Fiddler:

[image: Keycloak-loop]

This is my configuration

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);



        // When using authenticated() instead of hasRole() the authentication flow
        // returns a 401:Unauthenticated
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_CHECK_LIST).hasRole("mcd-role")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // If CSRF is enabled then POST requests return 303:Forbidden
        http.csrf().disable();
        // Allow executing Multipart upload requests
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }
```

Keycloak settings:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://[my-server]:8543/auth
keycloak.realm=AUTOTEST_PG
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=mcd-client
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.cors=true
```

Any help is appreciated.